# Group Python list of lists into groups based on overlapping items

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I have a list of lists and I am trying to group or cluster them based on their items. A nested list starts a new group if none of the elements are in the previous group.

**Input:**

```
paths = [  
        ['D', 'B', 'A', 'H'],  
        ['D', 'B', 'A', 'C'],  
        ['H', 'A', 'C'],  
        ['E', 'G', 'I'],  
        ['F', 'G', 'I']]
```

**My failed Code:**

```
paths = [
    ['D', 'B', 'A', 'H'],
    ['D', 'B', 'A', 'C'],
    ['H', 'A', 'C'],
    ['E', 'G', 'I'],
    ['F', 'G', 'I']
]
groups = []
paths_clone = paths
for path in paths:
    for node in path:
        for path_clone in paths_clone:
            if node in path_clone:
                if not path == path_clone:
                    groups.append([path, path_clone])
                else:
                    groups.append(path)
print groups
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[
 [
  ['D', 'B', 'A', 'H'],
  ['D', 'B', 'A', 'C'],
  ['H', 'A', 'C']
 ],
 [
  ['E', 'G', 'I'],
  ['F', 'G', 'I']
 ]
]
```

**Another Example:**

```
paths = [['shifter', 'barrel', 'barrel shifter'],
         ['ARM', 'barrel', 'barrel shifter'],
         ['IP power', 'IP', 'power'],
         ['ARM', 'barrel', 'shifter']]
```

**Expected Output Groups:**

```
output = [
         [['shifter', 'barrel', 'barrel shifter'],
         ['ARM', 'barrel', 'barrel shifter'],
         ['ARM', 'barrel', 'shifter']],
         [['IP power', 'IP', 'power']],
         ]
```

Comment: What defines a group? And `paths_clone` is a reference to the same list, not a copy. Use `paths[:]` to create a copy.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The group is basically all lists with overlapping items. As shown above, I need a way to cluster lists based on their items that are common with other lists.

Comment: So a new group starts when there are items in it that have not appeared in the previous group, or in the previous *item*?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes! Previous group

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are grouping based on sets, so use a set to detect new groups:

```
def grouper(sequence):
    group, members = [], set()

    for item in sequence:
        if group and members.isdisjoint(item):
            # new group, yield and start new
            yield group
            group, members = [], set()
        group.append(item)
        members.update(item)

    yield group
```

This gives:

```
>>> for group in grouper(paths):
...     print group
... 
[['D', 'B', 'A', 'H'], ['D', 'B', 'A', 'C'], ['H', 'A', 'C']]
[['E', 'G', 'I'], ['F', 'G', 'I']]
```

or you could cast it to a list again:

```
output = list(grouper(paths))
```

This assumes that the groups are contiguous. If you have disjoint groups, you need to process the whole list and loop over all groups constructed so far for each item:

```
def grouper(sequence):
    result = []  # will hold (members, group) tuples

    for item in sequence:
        for members, group in result:
            if members.intersection(item):  # overlap
                members.update(item)
                group.append(item)
                break
        else:  # no group found, add new
            result.append((set(item), [item]))

    return [group for members, group in result]
```

Comment: @Martjin I am not getting the same output. I am getting 4 groups. Where am I going wrong. [['D', 'B', 'A', 'H']]
[['D', 'B', 'A', 'C']]
[['H', 'A', 'C'], ['E', 'G', 'I']]
[['F', 'G', 'I']]

Comment: @ArunprasathShankar: check that you have the same function, there was an error in there at first (a `not` where it shouldn't be).

Comment: @Martjin Hi Martjin it fails for this case.                        paths = [['shifter', 'barrel', 'barrel shifter'],
         ['ARM', 'barrel', 'barrel shifter'],
         ['IP power', 'IP', 'power'],
         ['ARM', 'barrel', 'shifter']]                                  I get 3 groups instead of two groups :(                                            [['shifter', 'barrel', 'barrel shifter'], ['ARM', 'barrel', 'barrel shifter']]
[['IP power', 'IP', 'power']]
[['ARM', 'barrel', 'shifter']]

Comment: @ArunprasathShankar: That is because you didn't specify you had disjoint groups. That requires using a dictionary to create all groups in memory first.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters Can you give some insight on how would I accomplish this!

Comment: @ArunprasathShankar: There you go.

Comment: @Martjin Thanks a lot for your help!! I found an easier way using networkx module by converting the list of lists into a graph and extracting the connected_components.

Answer (score 4):

As with most questions in Python that start with "I'm trying to group… by foo…", the answer is "Use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with foo as a key."

---

First, let's take a very simple grouping criterion: length of each list. For that, the key function is just `len`. (You may also want to `sort` first, probably with the same key, depending on your data.)

```
groups = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(paths, len)]
```

---

Sometimes defining the grouping criterion (and therefore key function) is hard, or impossible, to define in terms of an independent transformation on each element. In those cases, `groupby` is generally not the answer (although `groupby` plus another `itertools` function still might be).

In this case, the most natural way to define the grouping criterion is by comparison with adjacent elements. The easiest way to write that is to write a `cmp` function that compares two adjacent elements, and then use [`functools.cmp_to_key`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) on it:

```
def cmp_paths(lhs, rhs):
    return 0 if any(key in lhs for key in rhs) else -1
key_paths = functools.cmp_to_key(cmp_paths)
groups = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(paths, key_paths)]
```

Comment: `defaultdict(list)` is the other alternative for grouping things (where `foo` is the key).  The advantage there is that the grouping is done in O(N) operations regardless of whether the input is sorted or not.  (but it does require that the key be hashable).

Comment: @abamert I am not trying to group the lists based on their lengths. I want to group them based on overlapping items across the lists as shown in the example above.

Comment: @ArunprasathShankar: What does "based on their items" mean? What is the actual rule that says whether or not two elements appear in the same group? You need to explain that in a way that human beings can understand before anyone can explain it in a way that Python can understand.

Comment: @abarnert Sorry for the vagueness. Rectified the comment. Please check it

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand the criterion… but it sounds like maybe you can write a `cmp` function for this pretty easily, and then use `cmp_to_key` to convert it to a key. So let me edit the answer.