# Group Python lists based on repeated items

Tags: python, algorithm, grouping

This question is very similar to this one [Group Python list of lists into groups based on overlapping items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306022/group-python-list-of-lists-into-groups-based-on-overlapping-items), in fact it could be called a duplicate.

Basically, I have a list of sub-lists where each sub-list contains some number of integers (this number is not the same among sub-lists). I need to group all sub-lists that share one integer or more.

The reason I'm asking a new separate question is because I'm attempting to adapt Martijn Pieters' [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16306257/1391441) with no luck.

Here's the MWE:

```
def grouper(sequence):
    result = []  # will hold (members, group) tuples

    for item in sequence:
        for members, group in result:
            if members.intersection(item):  # overlap
                members.update(item)
                group.append(item)
                break
        else:  # no group found, add new
            result.append((set(item), [item]))

    return [group for members, group in result]


gr = [[29, 27, 26, 28], [31, 11, 10, 3, 30], [71, 51, 52, 69],
      [78, 67, 68, 39, 75], [86, 84, 81, 82, 83, 85], [84, 67, 78, 77, 81],
      [86, 68, 67, 84]]

for i, group in enumerate(grouper(gr)):
    print 'g{}:'.format(i), group
```

and the output I get is:

```
g0: [[29, 27, 26, 28]]
g1: [[31, 11, 10, 3, 30]]
g2: [[71, 51, 52, 69]]
g3: [[78, 67, 68, 39, 75], [84, 67, 78, 77, 81], [86, 68, 67, 84]]
g4: [[86, 84, 81, 82, 83, 85]]
```

The last group `g4` should have been merged with `g3`, since the lists inside them share the items `81`, `83` and `84`, and even a single repeated element should be enough for them to be merged.

I'm not sure if I'm applying the code wrong, or if there's something wrong with the code.

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong; that code doesn't handle cases in which there are cascading merges because of the order it encounters things.  (E.g. `grouper([[1,1],[1,2],[2,2]])` works but `grouper([[1,1],[2,2],[1,2]])` doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can describe the merge you want to do as a set consolidation or as a connected-components problem.  I tend to use an off-the-shelf set consolidation algorithm and then adapt it to the particular situation.  For example, IIUC, you could use something like

```
def consolidate(sets):
    # http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Set_consolidation#Python:_Iterative
    setlist = [s for s in sets if s]
    for i, s1 in enumerate(setlist):
        if s1:
            for s2 in setlist[i+1:]:
                intersection = s1.intersection(s2)
                if intersection:
                    s2.update(s1)
                    s1.clear()
                    s1 = s2
    return [s for s in setlist if s]

def wrapper(seqs):
    consolidated = consolidate(map(set, seqs))
    groupmap = {x: i for i,seq in enumerate(consolidated) for x in seq}
    output = {}
    for seq in seqs:
        target = output.setdefault(groupmap[seq[0]], [])
        target.append(seq)
    return list(output.values())
```

which gives

```
>>> for i, group in enumerate(wrapper(gr)):
...     print('g{}:'.format(i), group)
...     
g0: [[29, 27, 26, 28]]
g1: [[31, 11, 10, 3, 30]]
g2: [[71, 51, 52, 69]]
g3: [[78, 67, 68, 39, 75], [86, 84, 81, 82, 83, 85], [84, 67, 78, 77, 81], [86, 68, 67, 84]]
```

(Order not guaranteed because of the use of the dictionaries.)

Comment: Wonderful answer DSM, you even solved an issue I didn't know I had. Thank you!

Comment: Off-the-shelf! - I guess so. I wrote the task and iterative Python solution, other members of Rosetta Code fleshed it out handsomely with all the other examples.  Take a look around the site @Gabriel, there's lots more where that came from :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like set consolidation if you turn each sub list into a set instead as you are interested in the contents not the order so sets are the best data-structure choice. See this: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Set_consolidation