# Merging pair set to list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, set

I have input set or list such as

input:

```
[[0,1],[0,2],[1,3],[4,5],[6]] or [[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[1,3],[4,5],[6]]
```

I want the output as

```
[[0,1,2,3],[4,5],[6]]
```

basically it will create list with the sharing pairs. The data type can differ. I am writing on python. Either pseudocode or the python code is welcome. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it? Also is it a set or a list (you show the latter) - that's a big difference.

Comment: if it is easier with set or tuple i can use and change the data type.

Comment: @Zek'iB.Ulu, what's the result for `[[6, 0, 1],[0,2],[1,3],[4,5],[6]]` ?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057777/group-python-lists-based-on-repeated-items

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting i found the answer:

```
def pairs_to_whole(touching_pairs:list):
    out = []
    while len(touching_pairs)>0:
        first, *rest = touching_pairs
        first = set(first)

        lf = -1
        while len(first)>lf:
            lf = len(first)

            rest2 = []
            for r in rest:
                if len(first.intersection(set(r)))>0:
                    first |= set(r)
                else:
                    rest2.append(r)     
            rest = rest2

        out.append(first)
        touching_pairs = rest
    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to use recursion:

```
def get_groups(d, l, s=[]):
   if not (r:=[i for i in d if any(j in l for j in i) and i not in s]):
      yield list(set(l))
      if (new_r:=[i for i in d if i not in s]):
         yield from get_groups(d, new_r[0], s=s+[new_r[0]])
   else:
      yield from get_groups(d, l+[i for k in r for i in k], s=s+r)

vals = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[1,3],[4,5],[6]]
print(list(get_groups(vals, vals[0])))
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But the code gave

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Comment: @Zek'iB.Ulu Can you post the input sample you tried it on?

Comment: i just run your whole code. input sample must be vals i suppose

Comment: @Zek'iB.Ulu Strange, it runs fine for me on both samples as well as `[[6, 0, 1],[0,2],[1,3],[4,5],[6]]` suggested by RomanPerekhrest. What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary of sets to represent the groups using the lowest value as key.  This will allow you to progressively merge groups by directly accessing the groups formed by their members.  Eliminating the merged subgroups progressively (until there are no more removals) will leave you with the desired grouping.

```
from collections import deque
def groupPairs(pairs):
    links    = dict()          # each value paired to a set of larger values
    addLinks = deque()         # values to be added to a group
    for a,*b in map(sorted,pairs):
        links[a] = set()       # create empty group for each lowest value
        addLinks.append((a,b)) # queue addition of paired values
    while addLinks: 
        a,values = addLinks.popleft()  # next addition of pairs 
        if not values or a not in links: continue
        links[a].update(values)       # add the paired values to the group
        addLinks.append((a,[c for b in values for c in links.pop(b,[])])) # remove and queue more
    return [ [k,*v] for k,v in links.items() ]

P = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,3],[4,5],[6]]
gp = groupPairs(P)
print(gp)
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]

P = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[1,3],[4,5],[6]]
gp = groupPairs(P)
print(gp)
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]

P = [[6, 0, 1],[0,2],[1,3],[4,5],[6]]
gp = groupPairs(P)
print(gp)
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 6], [4, 5]]
```