# grouping items in a list of lists containing tuples python

Tags: python, sorting

I haven't been doing python for long, and I'm pretty stuck on this problem. I have a list that contains may other lists each of which contain a varying number of tuples. I've tried using previously answered questions such as [grouping python lists of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306022/group-python-list-of-lists-into-groups-based-on-overlapping-items),[sorting and grouping nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409370/sorting-and-grouping-nested-lists-in-python)and other methods such as using counters, but none of them seem to work on my list, the output of which looks like this (This is my input data):

```
[('T0931', 'AB', '0.7826705747628963')] [('T0932', 'AB', '0.63950861050628')] [('T0933', 'AB', '0.8960345460457968'), ('T0933', 'AF', '0.8951297220212914'), ('T0933', 'BC', '0.8951297782393018'), ('T0933', 'CD', '0.8951298105762795'), ('T0933', 'DE', '0.8951299080330034'), ('T0933', 'EF', '0.8941510860547524')] [('T0932', 'AB', '0.63950861050628')] [('T0933', 'AB', '0.8960345460457968'), ('T0933', 'AF', '0.8951297220212914'), ('T0933', 'BC', '0.8951297782393018'), ('T0933', 'CD', '0.8951298105762795'), ('T0933', 'DE', '0.8951299080330034'), ('T0933', 'EF', '0.8941510860547524')]
```

I think my list (a list of tuples) is formatted differently to those used in other questions. When I ask its data type it comes up with list, tuple, string but prints these answers many times:

```
print(type(Data))
# Returns list
print(type(Data[0]))
# Returns tuple
print(type(Data[0][0]))
# Returns str

#output looks like this:
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
```

Even when I try to sort this list using sorted (2nd attempt), they all return variants of the same ungrouped list separated by many empty lists:

```
# Q is name of list
#attempt 1:    
def grouper(sequence):
            result = []  

            for item in sequence:
                    for members, group in result:
                            if members.intersection(item):  
                                    members.update(item)
                                    group.append(item)
                                    break
                    else:  
                            result.append((set(item), [item]))
            return [group for members, group in result]
    output=grouper(Q)
    print(output)

#attempt 2:
import itertools
    import operator
    Q=sorted(q,key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    for key,group in itertools.groupby(Q,operator.itemgetter(0)):
            print(list(group))

#attempt 3:
from collections import Counter
    C = Counter(Q)
    for list,v in C.items():
            print ([list,]*v)
```

I would like to group this list first by the TXXXX number at position 0 then by the two letters at position 1 whilst retaining all repeated elements in each group. However a detailed explanation of how to group the Txxxx number would be helpful so I can figure out how to do the same for the letters at position 1 myself. The desired output should look like the following:

```
[[('T0931', 'AB', '0.7826705747628963')],[('T0932', 'AB', '0.6395086105062'),('T0932', 'AB', '0.63950861050628')],[('T0933', 'AB', '0.8960345460457968'), ('T0933', 'AF', '0.8951297220212914'), ('T0933', 'BC', '0.8951297782393018'), ('T0933', 'CD', '0.8951298105762795'), ('T0933', 'DE', '0.8951299080330034'), ('T0933', 'EF', '0.8941510860547524'), ('T0933', 'AB', '0.8960345460457968'), ('T0933', 'AF', '0.8951297220212914'), ('T0933', 'BC', '0.8951297782393018'), ('T0933', 'CD', '0.8951298105762795'), ('T0933', 'DE', '0.8951299080330034'), ('T0933', 'EF', '0.8941510860547524')]]
```

Also in this case I don't believe making a dictionary will work (something I saw done in similar questions) as this is only a sample of the list, the full list contains many different Txxxx numbers at position 0.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From what you have provided I don't believe that your data is a list of lists. Could you also provide an expected input and desired output? It's a little confusing without being able to visually see what you want.

Comment: I've edited it to try to make it clearer, including the new output from the data type which had output from another part of the code mixed in causing the empty lists to occur in the original output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultdict` to keep all the values for each tx/code combination

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for group in q:
   for tx, code, value in group:
        d[tx, code].append(value)
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this method resulted in the error: `too many values to unpack (expected 3)`

Comment: @Emma Try, `for tx, code, *value in group: d[tx, code].append(value)`. Just add an `*` to value to allow any number of following items into the one variable. This should only be the case though if your tuples have more than 3 items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by, just like this :

```
my_list=[('T0931', 'AB', '0.7826705747628963'),('T0932', 'AB', '0.63950861050628'),
('T0933', 'AB', '0.8960345460457968'), ('T0933', 'AF', '0.8951297220212914'), 
('T0933', 'BC', '0.8951297782393018'), ('T0933', 'CD', '0.8951298105762795'), 
('T0933', 'DE', '0.8951299080330034'), ('T0933', 'EF', '0.8941510860547524'),
('T0932', 'AB', '0.63950861050628'),('T0933', 'AB', '0.8960345460457968'), 
('T0933', 'AF', '0.8951297220212914'), ('T0933', 'BC', '0.8951297782393018'), 
('T0933', 'CD', '0.8951298105762795'), ('T0933', 'DE', '0.8951299080330034'), 
('T0933', 'EF', '0.8941510860547524')]
import itertools

res =[]
for key, value in itertools.groupby(my_list, lambda x: x[0]):
    l=[]
    for val in value :
        l.append(val)
    res.append(l)
```

Output :

```
[[('T0931', 'AB', '0.7826705747628963')], [('T0932', 'AB', '0.63950861050628')], [('T0933', 'AB', '0.8960345460457968'), ('T0933', 'AF', '0.8951297220212914'), ('T0933', 'BC', '0.8951297782393018'), ('T0933', 'CD', '0.8951298105762795'), ('T0933', 'DE', '0.8951299080330034'), ('T0933', 'EF', '0.8941510860547524')], [('T0932', 'AB', '0.63950861050628')], [('T0933', 'AB', '0.8960345460457968'), ('T0933', 'AF', '0.8951297220212914'), ('T0933', 'BC', '0.8951297782393018'), ('T0933', 'CD', '0.8951298105762795'), ('T0933', 'DE', '0.8951299080330034'), ('T0933', 'EF', '0.8941510860547524')]]
```

Comment: @ KHELILI Hamza is there a way to make the output look more like `[[('T0931', 'AB', '0.7826705747628963')],[('T0932', 'AB', '0.6395086105062'),('T0932', 'AB', '0.63950861050628')],[('T0933', 'AB', '0.8960345460457968'), ('T0933', 'AF', '0.8951297220212914'), ('T0933', 'BC', '0.8951297782393018'), ('T0933', 'CD', '0.8951298105762795'), ('T0933', 'DE', '0.8951299080330034'), ('T0933', 'EF', '0.8941510860547524'), ('T0933', 'AB', '0.8960345460457968' ...)]]` so that each Txxxx number has its own list with all the instances of the tuples containing that Txxxx number in that list?