# Group nested lists of tuples by two repeating elements

Tags: python, list, grouping

I have a nested list of tuples:

```
[[(1236.39, -693.34), (1236.8, -697.38), (1236.39, -697.38)],
[(1236.8, -693.34), (1236.39, -693.34), (1236.8, -697.38)],
[(1240.64, -693.15), (1236.6, -693.56), (1236.6, -693.15)],
[(1240.64, -693.56), (1240.64, -693.15), (1236.6, -693.56)],
[(1237.17, -697.82), (1237.19, -697.34), (1237.0, -697.69)],
[(1237.45, -697.53), ([1237.17, -697.82), (1237.19, -697.34)]]
```

How to group them by two repeating tuples in the lower list:

```
[[[(1236.39, -693.34), (1236.8, -697.38), (1236.39, -697.38)],
[(1236.8, -693.34), (1236.39, -693.34), (1236.8, -697.38)]],
[[(1240.64, -693.15), (1236.6, -693.56), (1236.6, -693.15)],
[(1240.64, -693.56), (1240.64, -693.15), (1236.6, -693.56)]],
[(1237.17, -697.82), (1237.19, -697.34), (1237.0, -697.69)],
[(1237.45, -697.53), ([1237.17, -697.82), (1237.19, -697.34)]]
```

i.e. It's like grouping triangles having the common edge.
I tried solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306022/group-python-list-of-lists-into-groups-based-on-overlapping-items) question, but it returns me wrong result:

```
    [[(1236.8, -693.34), (1236.39, -693.34), (1236.8, -697.38)]]
    [[(1240.64, -693.15), (1236.6, -693.56), (1236.6, -693.15)], [(1240.64, -693.56), (1240.64, -693.15), (1236.6, -693.56)]]
    [[(1237.17, -697.82), (1237.19, -697.34), (1237.0, -697.69)], [(1237.45, -697.53), (1237.17, -697.82), (1237.19, -697.34)]]
    [[(1236.39, -693.34), (1236.8, -697.38), (1236.39, -697.38)]]
```

It correctly groups lists in the middle, but lists on the edge are not grouped.

Comment: Are you just trying to nest each sub list in pairs?

Comment: Not in pairs exactly. Just grouping lists inside each list if they share two tuples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby` to group the items  and a function to check the repeating elements which can be used in `groupby` as `key` with `functools.cmp_to_key` same as mentioned in answers of question you shared.

```
from itertools import groupby as gby
import functools
def check_common(a, b):
    return 0 if any(key in a for key in b) else -1
```

Result:

```
>>> key_common = functools.cmp_to_key(check_common)
>>> groups = [list(group) for key, group in gby(input_list, key=key_common)]
>>> groups
>>> [[[(1236.39, -693.34), (1236.8, -697.38), (1236.39, -697.38)], 
      [(1236.8, -693.34), (1236.39, -693.34), (1236.8, -697.38)]], 
     [[(1240.64, -693.15), (1236.6, -693.56), (1236.6, -693.15)], 
      [(1240.64, -693.56), (1240.64, -693.15), (1236.6, -693.56)]], 
     [[(1237.17, -697.82), (1237.19, -697.34), (1237.0, -697.69)], 
      [(1237.45, -697.53), (1237.17, -697.82), (1237.19, -697.34)]]
    ]
```

Comment: Yes, for this relatively short example your solution is working, but it very depends on the order of input_list, in other words, if I try to sort the original list I finally receive other result. When I apply your solution to the longer list it returns me a list of lists consisting of small chains of elements, while in fact, almost all elements should be grouped.